# Not getting expected output in descending order

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a[4] = {20, 4, 7, 8};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; 
j++)
        {
           if (a[i] < a[j])
            {
                a[i] = a[j];
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
        a[0] = 20;
        a[1] = 4;
        a[2] = 7;
        a[3] = 8;
    }
}
```

I simply trying to show the output as descending order but not getting expected result

Expected :
20
8
7
4

Error follows:
20
20
20
20

- Please help me to rectify ..

Comment: All sorting involves *swapping* values. You don't swap any values, you only assign. And then you assign the original values inside the loop, which makes no sense if you want to sort.

Comment: Do you mean ascending order? In English it's ascending order (small to large) *or* descending order (large to small). Ascending to Descending order doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Omm Think about what swapping does and what `a[i] = a[j];`means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't *swapping* `a[i]` with `a[j]`, you're simply copying the value of `a[j]` to `a[i]`.

To do a swap, you need *three* operations:

```
int tmp = a[i];  // save the value of a[i]
a[i] = a[j];     // write a[j] to a[i]
a[j] = tmp;      // write saved value of a[i] to a[j]
```